# Word for 'Understanding future consequences'

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm trying to find a word that describes the 'skill' of understanding the future consequences of an action or event, to accurately predict events based on a mental model. Prescience or Foreknowledge don't really work, as they suggest knowing through some magical ability. Many other synonyms don't work either - such as precognition, presage, or foreboding - all for the same reason.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What are “future” consequences supposed to be that’s somehow distinct from “non-future” consequences? Isn’t the collocation *future consequences* tautological?

Comment: As opposed to immediate consequences. I can say long term consequences if you prefer, but it won't help answer my question.

Comment: *foresight*? Abcd

Comment: Why do you think there is a single word that means "understanding consequences" (future or not)? And what do you specifically mean by *consequences*? It's also not clear what's wrong with the word *prediction* itself.

Comment: I don't, I'm asking if there is. That's the whole point. As it happens, there is, as has been pointed out by far more helpful people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prognosticator** - "one who predicts future events or developments"

> one of the best prognosticators in the weather business

Source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prognosticator)

Comment: This fits perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**[foresight](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/foresight)** (dictionary.com)

1. care or provision for the future; provident care; prudence.
2. the act or power of foreseeing; prevision; prescience.
3. an act of looking forward.
4. knowledge or insight gained by or as by looking forward; a view of
   the future.
5. Surveying.

   a) a sight or reading taken on a forward point.

   b) (in leveling) a rod reading on a point the elevation of which is to be determined.

Comment: Thank you, it's so simple I completely overlooked this one.